# Python kivy _instance_ of Widget

Tags: python, kivy

I started coding my python kivy app, but I am having some problems:
`App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget`. I saw some topics about it, but I still don't understand it. Even when I tried to Google it. Code is here:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn1 = Button(text ="btn1",
                   font_size ="20sp",
                   background_color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   size =(32, 32),
                   size_hint =(.2, .2),
                   pos =(50, 425))
        

        btn2 = Button(text ="btn2",
                font_size ="20sp",
                background_color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                size =(32, 32),
                size_hint =(.2, .2),
                pos =(50, 50))
        
        return btn1, btn2

TestApp().run()
```

Thanks for help

Comment: The `build()` method is supposed to return a single widget, the root of the hierarchy you're creating.  A tuple of two Buttons is not acceptable.  (One Button would work, although you'd normally return some sort of layout object that contains your Buttons.)

Comment: Have a look at [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html#create-an-application) for some examples.